# Errors in imported library

Tags: android, eclipse, import

I want to use this library to crop images, since the crop intent can cause problems on certain devices: https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage

If I import it in Eclipse however, I get some errors in Eclipse.

In the Util class I get an error on this

```
options.inNativeAlloc = true;
```

inNativeAlloc cannot be resolved. Also I get another error in the CropImage class:

```
MenuHelper.showStorageToast(this);
```

The MenuHelper class isn't included in the library.

Since if seen these kind of errors on another library I want to know if there is something that I'm missing or doing wrong.

I'm saving the library as a zip file, extract the zipfile and import the library folder in Eclipse by using import > Existing Android Code into Workspace. I think this is ok since I checked the source on Github to comfirm if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a new issue for the project as you [can see on the issue page](https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage/issues/6). To solve it you could follow the recommendations made in that post or you could download/get the [`develop`](https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage/tree/develop)(the same way) branch which, at a quick look, doesn't seem to have those problems.

Answer (score 0):

The project that you are using already is an android library. You should just download the entire source folder and use Import existing project (the .project file is already in github).

Then in your own project create a reference to it by going into project properties -> android -> library -> add

Comment: I tried downloading the entire source, imported it as a project. Still the same errors in the library.

Answer (score 0):

About **inNativeAlloc** - it is a hidden field... To set a "true" value to it you must use this code: [setInNativeAllocTrue(opts)](https://code.google.com/p/androidcommons/source/browse/trunk/util/src/main/java/com/androidcommons/util/BitmapUtil.java#282)